# HTML Functions not working under SSL

Tags: ssl, youtube, embed

I'm having trouble with my website and some background music using Youtube Embed snippet.

When I connect without SSL everything works fine, from JS to YT snippets.
But when I use SSL, YT snippet doesn't work.

```
<embed height="1" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/-hIbRH1qcjU?autoplay=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="1" wmode="transparent">
```

Any ideas on how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you view the browser console you'll probably see a message about mixed content. You're including content that is http on a https site.

Just change the Youtube URL to be https and not http and I suspect it will work.

Comment: If this helped then accept this answer by clicking the tick icon. Cheers